# Showing no questions with tag "android"

Tags: discussion, bug

As usual I was browsing through the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag questions, but I suddenly started seeing no questions found.

Below is the screenshot of the same.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Comment: So they finally banned [android]? It was long overdue...

Comment: Can't reproduce: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) shows a ton of questions for me.

Comment: Now it is showing for me too. Seems like a temporary issue.

Comment: Add tag `status-norepro`?